# FFMPEG on MACOSX is complaining "no matches found"

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, command-line

I have a FFMPEG command line function that works perfectly on Windows but on Mac produces the following error:

"no matches found [1:a]adelay=15000:all=1[aud2]"
"no matches found [2:a]adelay=5000:all=1[aud3]"

Here is the command (less the full paths which just made it very hard to read).  I've verified that the files exist at the paths specified by copying the file path from the command line and going into terminal, typing "open" then pasting in the copied path and pressing enter.  In all cases they played.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -hide_banner -y -i "file1.mp3" -t 5 -i "file2.mp3" -i "file3.mp3" -i "file4.mp3" -ss 25 -t 15 -i "file5.mp3" -ss 15 -t 5 -i "file6.mp3" -filter_complex [1:a]adelay=15000:all=1[aud1];[2:a]adelay=5000:all=1[aud2];[4:a]adelay=25000:all=1[aud4];[5:a]adelay=5000:all=1[aud5];[aud1][aud2][aud4][aud5]amix=inputs=6:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0:normalize=0 "output.mp3"
```

I know the immediate response (as it should be), is update your FFMPEG but I got the latest build (built on 2022-06-12) and here's what it reports...

```
ffmpeg version N-107092-g843c4346b1-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavcodec     59. 33.100 / 59. 33.100
  libavformat    59. 24.100 / 59. 24.100
  libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavfilter     8. 40.100 /  8. 40.100
  libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Any insight or help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  I finally tracked it down.   I needed to put everything following the -filter_complex up until the output file in a set of double quotes.